# Usar variable $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, angularjs-scope, scope

Tengo una función donde obtengo parámetros de una API via $http.post, los parametros que retorna se guardan bien y se imprimen dentro de la misma petición, sin embargo cuando requiero usarlos fuera la variable aparece vacía.

```
$scope.gama = {};

factoryGamas.buscarGama_x_nombre( objCons.gama ).then(function(reponse){
    $scope.gama = reponse.data.fields;
});
```

Si hago un **console.log( $scope.gama )** el resultado es vacío, o en este caso **{}**

Pero al hacer un console.log dentro de la funcion si me retorna los valores.

```
factoryGamas.buscarGama_x_nombre( objCons.gama ).then(function(reponse){
        $scope.gama = reponse.data.fields;
        console.log( $scope.gama );
    });
```

¿De qué forma podría usar la variable fuera de la función si ya la estoy usando dentro del $scope?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se encuentra dentro del **then()** se maneja en un scope diferente. El $scope que estas asignando los datos del response no es el mismo. Una forma sencilla de evitar este problema es creando una variable donde guardar el scope.

```
var self = $scope;
factoryGamas.buscarGama_x_nombre( objCons.gama ).then(function(reponse){
    self.gama = reponse.data.fields;
});
```

De esta manera estas asignando la respuesta a una variable del scope externo y ya está disponible para ser usada.

Comment: Gracias, sin embargo el problema aún persiste. Lo que me dí cuenta es que si le pongo un setTimeout(function(){ console.log( $scope.gama ); }, 3000); el $scope, si me arroja el contenido (después de 3 seg).  Esa forma no me parece optima. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @jmrtn Eso solo significaría que estas llamando a la variable antes de que buscarGama_x_nombre() traiga el resultado, imagino yo de la base de datos. Recuerda que las llamadas de javascript son asíncronas. Lo que se ejecuta dentro del **then()** sucede después de respondida la llamada. Por eso ahí si existe el valor y afuera donde lo llamas no. Te recomiendo validar primero que haya traído la respuesta antes de usar el valor.